# NMR Analysis of Ethylene glycol

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, data-analysis

I have the spectrum obtained by an NMR analysis of Ethylene glycol :

[image: Structural formula of ethylene glycol]
[image: Ethylene glycol NMR spectrum]

I would like to explain the number of peaks in this spectrum,

and assign them to the proton spins present in the molecule.

I would say that one of the picks is due to the OH groups, and the other one to the CH$_2$, but I don't understand very well the physics behind this.

Could anyone try to explain me ?

Thanks for your help (and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: The area under the peaks is proportional to the number of H atoms. Since there are 4 CH and 2 OH bonds the larger peak is the CH hydrogens.

Comment: @ManishEarth : Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I studied NMR recently, it seems like physics to me. Maybe nulcear physics isn't the best tag ever, but [Experimental-physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/experimental-physics/info) might be a good one. The physical understanding of the NMR spectrum is quite interesting.

Comment: I have nothing constructive to add, but that is a *really* nice spectrum if you obtained that experimentally with what I assume is a student lab setup, judging by the language of your question. I don't recall ever getting such a clean trace from anything.

Comment: Actually this is a computational physics homework, there was only this question about physical interpretation, I didn't acquired the nmr results by myself, I have only treated the signal. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right when you say that one peak is due to $\mathrm{OH}$ groups and the other one to $\mathrm{CH_2}$ groups. The protons in each groups are chemically equivalent and contribute to the same peak.

You should compute the area below each peak.

Since there are 4 $\mathrm{CH_2}$ protons and only 2 $\mathrm{OH}$ protons, my guess is that one peak's area is two times greater.

The chemical shift is in general greater for protons near oxygen. Then the left peak may be assigned to $\mathrm{OH}$ group.

To verify this you should check peak's areas.

Answer (score 1):

Fast rotation keeps the paper-symmetry protons equivalent.  High concentration makes for fast proton exchange in the alcohols (sharp line, no coupling to methylene protons).  Integration identifies populations.  The difference in chemical shifts tells you the temperature of the sample,

http://www.emerypharmaservices.com/blog/calibration-variable-temperature-nmr-thermocouple 
http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~liuyz/methods/NMR_VT_calibration.htm 
   with calibration equation.

Are there C-13 satellites?